# Converting a Python list into a pandas dataframe while specifying certain elements as row labels

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the below list called my_list and want to convert it to a new pandas dataframe where the strings starting with 'I=' will become the dataframe's row labels.

```
my_list=['I=113',
 'PLAN=1',
 'A=0PDFGB',
 'B=23FGC',
 'C=26TGFGD',
 'D=19TGE',
 'E=18TGA',
 'I=120',
 'PLAN=2',
 'A=0PDFGB',
 'B=23FGC',
 'C=26TGFGD',
 'D=19TGE',
 'E=18TGA',
 'I=113',
 'PLAN=2',
 'A=0PDFGB',
 'B=23FGC',
 'C=26TGFGD',
 'D=19TGE',
 'E=18TGA']
```

The output will look like the below:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
I=113|PLAN=1|A=0PDFGB|B=23FGC|C=26TGFGD|D=19TGE|E=18TGA
--------------------------------------------------------
I=120|PLAN=2|A=0PDFGB|B=23FGC|C=26TGFGD|D=19TGE|E=18TGA
-------------------------------------------------------
```

and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use a loop cut the list into sublists and use the DataFrame constructor:

```
tmp = []
for item in my_list:
    if item.startswith('I'):
        tmp.append([])
    tmp[-1].append(item)
out = pd.DataFrame(tmp)
```

Output:

```
       0       1         2        3          4        5        6
0  I=113  PLAN=1  A=0PDFGB  B=23FGC  C=26TGFGD  D=19TGE  E=18TGA
1  I=120  PLAN=2  A=0PDFGB  B=23FGC  C=26TGFGD  D=19TGE  E=18TGA
2  I=113  PLAN=2  A=0PDFGB  B=23FGC  C=26TGFGD  D=19TGE  E=18TGA
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `np.reshape`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(my_list, (-1, 7)))
print(df)

# Output
       0       1         2        3          4        5        6
0  I=113  PLAN=1  A=0PDFGB  B=23FGC  C=26TGFGD  D=19TGE  E=18TGA
1  I=120  PLAN=2  A=0PDFGB  B=23FGC  C=26TGFGD  D=19TGE  E=18TGA
2  I=113  PLAN=2  A=0PDFGB  B=23FGC  C=26TGFGD  D=19TGE  E=18TGA
```

**Update**

You can also split your values into:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x.split('=') for x in my_list], columns=['col', 'val']) \
       .assign(row=lambda x: x['col'].eq('I').cumsum()).pivot('row', 'col', 'val') \
       .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
print(df)

# Output
        A      B        C      D      E    I PLAN
1  0PDFGB  23FGC  26TGFGD  19TGE  18TGA  113    1
2  0PDFGB  23FGC  26TGFGD  19TGE  18TGA  120    2
3  0PDFGB  23FGC  26TGFGD  19TGE  18TGA  113    2
```